# Disable Automatic Maven Comments in Jira

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-plugin, jira-rest-api

Maven has been, seemingly, randomly inserting comments into Jira tickets suddenly. Issue was not present before and there were no changes made that correlate to when Maven started adding comments.

Currently using Maven plug-ins for Jenkin's Jobs:

```
- Maven Artifact ChoiceListProvider 1.8.1
- Maven Dependency Update Trigger 1.5
- Maven Deployment Linker 1.5.1
- Maven Info Plugin 0.3.0
- Maven Integration Plugin 3.10
- Maven Invoker Plugin 2.4
- Maven Metadata Plugin for Jenkins Server 2.0.0
```

I do not know if these plugins are related to Maven's ability to add comments though.

The Maven comments follow the following format:

> SUCCESS: Integrated in Jenkins build xyz #123 (See <internal link>)

I have tried looking into the local configs for Jira as well as looking through Jenkin's to see if there was the ability to configure Maven. I do not have Jira admin rights or I would look at that too.
I did try Googling using multiple different variations of the issue with no luck. I am not sure what I am missing here or if I can even create a configuration for Maven that disables the automatic commenting abilities.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `Maven has been, seemingly, randomly inserting comments into Jira tickets suddenly.` there is nothing randomly doing such things it means there is a configuration in your setup (pom files)... or it's configured in your Jenkins pipeline which updates the entries in JIRA...and `and there were no changes made that correlate to when Maven started adding comments.` this must be wrong...

Comment: @khmarbaise Where would the pom files be? Where would that be configured in Jenkins?

Comment: The pom file is part of your project...